# How to get checked checkbox table value in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my table I have 2 rows please [see my screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TQXc.png),suppose I click first check box means I want to take that **id **  and  **to_area** value  in jquery how can do this,I tried but I can not get please help some one

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#chemist_allotment_btn').click(function() {
    if ($('#chemist_allotment_form').valid()) {
      $.ajax({
        url: 'update_chemist_bulk_transfer.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('form#chemist_allotment_form').serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
          var res = jQuery.parseJSON(data); // convert the json
          console.log(res);
          if (res['status'] == 1) {
            var htmlString = '';
            $.each(res['data'], function(key, value) {
              htmlString += '<tr>';
              htmlString += ' <td class="sorting_1"><div class="checkbox-custom checkbox-success"><input type="checkbox" id="checkboxExample3" name="getchemist" class="getchemist" value="' + value.id + '"><label for="checkboxExample3"></label></div></td>';
              htmlString += '<td>' + value.id + '</td>';
              htmlString += '<td>' + value.name + '</td>';
              htmlString += '<td>' + value.area + '</td>';
              htmlString += '<td>' + value.to_area + '</td>';
              htmlString += '<td>' + value.address + '</td>';
              htmlString += '</tr>';

            });
            $('#SampleDT tbody').empty().append(htmlString);


            $('#get_to_area').click(function() {
              var id = $('input[name=getchemist]:checked').val();
              if ($(".getchemist").prop('checked') == true) {
                alert(id);
                alert(value.to_area);
              } else {
                alert('Please Check');
              }
            });


          } else {
            $('#SampleDT tbody').empty().append('No Datas Found');
          }
        },
      });
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="well white">
  <table id="SampleDT" class="datatable table table-hover table-striped table-bordered tc-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Select</th>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Doctor Name</th>
        <th>From Area</th>
        <th>To Area</th>
        <th>Address</th>
      </tr>

    </thead>
    <tbody>


    </tbody>

  </table>

  <center>
    <div class="form-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="text-align:left;" id="get_to_area">Transfer Area</button>
    </div>
  </center>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if a checkbox is checked in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901712/how-do-i-check-if-a-checkbox-is-checked-in-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, add classes to each `<td>`, like `<td class='id'>[Your id]</td>`

Similarly for all the elements `doctor-name`, `to-area`, etc and a class to each `<tr>` like `row-select`

Somewhat like this:

```
<tr class="row-select">
  <td class="select">...</td>
  <td class="id">...</td>
  <td class="to-area">...</td>
  .
  .
  .
</tr>
```

Use jQuery like this:

```
$('.row-select').click(function(){
    var id,toArea,checkBox;
    id = $(this).find('.id').html(); //get the ID field
    toArea = $(this).find('.to-area').html(); //get the to-area field
    checkBox = $(this).find('.select > input');
    checkbox.prop('checked',!checkbox.prop('checked'));
})
```

This code will get you he value no mater where you click on the row, and also invert the selection on the checkbox

To get the values of rows selected when the form is submitted run a loop like this

```
$('.row-select input:checked').each(function(){
        var id,toArea,checkBox;
        id = $(this).closest('tr').find('.id').html(); //get the ID field
        toArea = $(this).closest('tr').find('.to-area').html(); //get the to-area field
})
```

**EDIT**

All together:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#btnSubmit').click(function() {

    $('.row-select input:checked').each(function() {
      var id, name;
      id = $(this).closest('tr').find('.id').html();
      name = $(this).closest('tr').find('.name').html();

      alert('ID: ' + id + " | Name: " + name);
    })

  })


  $('#btnSelectAll').click(function() {

    $('.row-select input').each(function() {
      $(this).prop('checked', true);
    })

  })

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border=1>
  <tr class="row-select">
    <td class="check">
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td class="id">12</td>
    <td class="name">Jones</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="row-select">
    <td class="check">
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td class="id">10</td>
    <td class="name">Joseph</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id="btnSelectAll">Select all</button>
<button id="btnSubmit">Get Value</button>
```

Comment: Possible means give me jsfiddle please

Comment: Then u gotta wait for few moments

Comment: There.. I added a sinippet

Comment: Mr @Jones Joseph your answer is sutable for me ,but i need one more option i need to give select all option,that time i want get all values how can do this please help me

Comment: When clicking on select all just iterate through each checkbox and do `prop('checked',true);` on them. After this when user submits, you will automatically have all values

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pandeyvishal1986/roxnuedq/#&togetherjs=UQfh4SAbg2):

In JS:

```
$('#get_to_area').click(function () {
    var id = $('input[name=getchemist]:checked').val();
if ($('input[name=getchemist]').is(':checked')) {
        var ID = $('input[name=getchemist]').parent().parent().siblings('td.chkid').html();
        var TO_Area = $('input[name=getchemist]').parent().parent().siblings('td.toarea').html();
    } 
    else {
    alert('Please Check');
    }
    });
```

In Html:

```
if (res['status'] == 1) {
                                var htmlString = '';
                                $.each(res['data'], function (key, value) {
                                    htmlString += '<tr>';
                                    htmlString += ' <td class="sorting_1"><div class="checkbox-custom checkbox-success"><input type="checkbox" id="checkboxExample3" name="getchemist" class="getchemist" value="' + value.id + '"><label for="checkboxExample3"></label></div></td>';
                                    htmlString += '<td class="chkid">' + value.id + '</td>';
                                    htmlString += '<td>' + value.name + '</td>';
                                    htmlString += '<td>' + value.area + '</td>';
                                    htmlString += '<td class="toarea">' + value.to_area + '</td>';
                                    htmlString += '<td>' + value.address + '</td>';
                                    htmlString += '</tr>';

                                });
```

Comment: Nothing i will get possible means give one js fiddle

Comment: please find sample [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pandeyvishal1986/roxnuedq/#&togetherjs=UQfh4SAbg2)

Answer (score 0):

### Process step-by-step:

1. Give the `td` you need some classes (**from-a** & **to-a**);
2. Initialize an empty array **all** (we'll store the data inside it later on);
3. Create a function that is triggered by the checkbox *change*
4. Inside the function you need to know which checkbox has changed, what's the state of it, what `tr` does it belong to and at the end what are the **TO AREA** and **FROM AREA** values.
5. If the state = **checked** we will add the values to the **all** (our small data storage);
6. If the state = **not-checked** we will remove the value from the **all** array;
7. Finally when we are done with selecting and deselecting rows by pressing the button we can get the values of the selected rows.

```js
var all = [];

$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
  var checkbox = $(this);
  var state = checkbox.prop('checked');
  var tr = checkbox.parents('tr');
  var from = tr.children('.from-a').text();
  var to = tr.children('.to-a').text();
    
  if(state){
    all.push(from + ' -> ' + to);
  }else{
    var index = all.indexOf(from + ' -> ' + to);
    
    all.splice(index, 1);
  }
})

$('#get_to_area').click(function(){
  alert(all);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <div class="well white">
    <table id="SampleDT" class="datatable table table-hover table-striped table-bordered tc-table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Select</th>
          <th>Id</th>
          <th>Doctor Name</th>
          <th>From Area</th>
          <th>To Area</th>
          <th>Address</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr id="1">
          <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Nick</td>
          <td class="from-a">Kosur</td>
          <td class="to-a">Nath Pari</td>
          <td>Address</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="2">
          <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>John</td>
          <td class="from-a">Rusok</td>
          <td class="to-a">iraP htaN</td>
          <td>sserddA</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <center>
      <div class="form-group">
        <button style="text-align:left;" id="get_to_area">Transfer Area</button>
      </div>
    </center>
  </div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

> *This is just the basic concept, you can modify it to suit your needs, I'll be happy to help you if you get stuck.*

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing you need values of each `td` whose checbox are checked. This piece of code should get you started.

As you can see, Code loops through each `checkbox` which is `checked`, gets contents inside its corresponding `td`.

```
var Result = new Array();
    $('.checkbox-custom input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(){
         var _this = $(this).closest('tr').find('td');
         var id= $(_this).eq(0);
         var name = $(_this).eq(1);
         ................... //Similar way for the others

         Result.Push(id,name,....)
    });
```

Comment: I nedd like this answer but when i am clicking the submit button that time i need answer like this

Comment: @SujiniR I have updated my answer. Go through it once.